# How to prove the set distributive law for $n$ sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How do you show that if you have sets $B_1, B_2, \cdots ,B_n$ and a set  $C$, then 
$$(B_1\cap B_2, \cap \cdots B_n)\cup C= (B_1\cup C)\cap(B_2\cup C) \cap \cdots 
\cap (B_n\cup C)\,?$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$( B_1\cap B_2)\cup C = (B_1\cup C)\cap(B_2 \cup C).$$
Use an induction argument.

Comment: Huh? this syntax makes no sense to me.

Comment: What part of the syntax makes no sense?

Comment: my bad it works now

Comment: how would you start the inductive argument

Comment: @tim29 Induction arguments have base cases and inductive steps. The base case is what ncmathsadist wrote in his answer. The inductive step involves assuming that your statement is true for $n=k$, and proving that it holds for $n=k+1$. The base case is the same as your equation if we set $n=2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove the most general version without induction.

[image]

**Corollary** of *(ii)* $$ \begin{align*}
(B_1\cap B_2\cap\cdots \cap B_n)\cup C&= \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}B_i\right)\cup C\\
&=\bigcap_{i=1}^n(B_i\cup C)\\
&=(B_1\cup C)\cap(B_2\cup C)\cap\cdots\cap(B_n\cup C)
\end{align*} $$